# what's the different between "%0.6X" and "%06X" in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

what's the different between ***"%0.6X"*** and ***"%06X"*** in python ?

```
def formatTest():
    print "%0.6X" %1024
    print "%06X" %1024

if __name__=='__main__':
    formatTest()
```

The result is :

```
000400
000400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

> A conversion specifier contains two or more characters and has the following components, which must occur in this order:
>
> 1. The `'%'` character, which marks the start of the specifier.
> 2. Mapping key (optional), consisting of a parenthesised sequence of characters (for example, `(somename)`).
> 3. Conversion flags (optional), which affect the result of some conversion types.
> 4. Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an `'*'` (asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional precision.
> 5. Precision (optional), given as a `'.'` (dot) followed by the precision. If specified as `'*'` (an asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the value to convert comes after the precision.
> 6. Length modifier (optional).
> 7. Conversion type.

So the documentation doesn't clearly state what the interaction of width versus precision is. Let's explore some more.

```
>>> '%.4X' % 1024
'0400'
>>> '%6.4X' % 1024
'  0400'
>>> '%#.4X' % 1024
'0x0400'
>>> '%#8.4X' % 1024
'  0x0400'
>>> '%#08.4X' % 1024
'0x000400'
```

Curious. It appears that width (the part before `.`) controls the whole field, and space-pads by default, unless flagged with `0`. Precision (the part after `.`) controls only the integer part, and always `0`-pads.

---

Let's take a look at new-style formatting. It's the future! (And by future I mean it's available now and has been for many years.)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

> *width* is a decimal integer defining the minimum field width. If not specified, then the field width will be determined by the content.
>
> When no explicit alignment is given, preceding the *width* field by a zero (`'0'`) character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of `'0'` with an alignment type of `'='`.
>
> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`. For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content. The *precision* is not allowed for integer values.

Much more clearly specified! `{0:06X}` is valid, `{0:0.6X}` is not.

```
>>> '{0:06x}'.format(1024)
'000400'
>>> '{0:0.6x}'.format(1024)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier
```

Answer (score 0):

These happen to be equivalent. That doesn't mean you can always ignore the `.`, though; the reason for the equivalence is pretty specific and doesn't generalize.

`0.6X` specifies a *precision* of 6, whereas `06X` specifies a minimum field width of 6. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) doesn't say what a *precision* does for the X conversion type, but Python follows the behavior of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) here, where a *precision* for `X` is treated as a minimum number of digits to print.

With `06X`, the formatting produces at least 6 digits, adding leading zeros if necessary. With `0.6X`, the formatting produces a result at least 6 characters wide. The result would be padded with spaces, but the `0` says to pad with zeros instead. Overall, the behavior works out to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

`06` means that the data passed in, if less than 6 digits long will be prepended by 0 to fill that space. The `x` denotes the type of data, in this case the format string is expecting a hexadecimal number.

1024 in hexadecimal is 400, which is why you get `000400` as your result.

For `0.6x`, the `.` denotes the precision (width) of characters to be shown. So, `%0.6x` means:

- `%` - start of the format string specification
- A `0`, which means that for numerical values, pad them by 0 to meet the format specification.
- A `.` which precision modifier. The number after this (6) is how much width to give for the precision characters.
- Finally, the `x` which is the conversion type, in this case hexadecimal.

Since hexadecimal numbers don't have float components, the results of both those operations are the same.